# Java - Make a simple SQL call

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I have an app where the user inputs some SQL string on a input box and I want to return the JSON data for that string.

I have the string, now how do I fetch the data and return it?

Is there a way to make this more secure and only allow the user to select stuff and not update/drop/delete?

```
@RequestMapping("/api")
@RestController
public class Controller {

    @GetMapping
    public List<Object> returnData(@RequestParam String query) {
       //return the data from que query
    }
}
```

I'm using JPA + Hibernate + Spring Boot

Comment: The question is, what is the purpose to do something like this?

Comment: I want to generate .json files with the data to test another app. This is a app only used by me.

Comment: Then to make it secure make a role (authorization) just for your account

Comment: This is only used by me, I dont need security.

Comment: What database are you using? MariaDB?

Comment: Oracle Database version 12

Comment: Saying stuff like *noone knows this? this should be basic stuff* is considered rude around here. If it was so basic to you why didn't you find it by googling ? Please refrain from making comments like that one in the future. This is a site where you ask for help, and trying to mock the people that are trying to help you sucks.

Comment: *Is there a way to make this more secure and only allow the user to select stuff and not update/drop/delete?* - yes, with grants/permissions on the database level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate` in order to execute plain sql.
Just create a simple bean:

```
  @Bean
  public JdbcTemplate healthJdbcTemplate(DataSource dataSource) {
    return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
  }
```

You can autowire the jdbcTemplate and execute plain sql queries

```
@Autowired
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
```

After that, you can use the `queryForList` method to get the required data. 
For example, if you have a persons table with the following data:

```
id  first_name last_name, add_info, company_id
1      fn1       ln1       info1        1
2      fn2       ln2       info2        1
3      fn3       ln3       info3        1
4      fn4       ln4       info4        1
```

And a company table :

```
id company_name
1  test_company1
```

And you use the following code to retrieve the data :

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

@RestController
public class Controller {

    @Autowired
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @GetMapping("/api/test")
    List<Map<String, Object>> getData() {
        return jdbcTemplate.queryForList("Select * FROM public.persons p JOIN public.companies c" +
                " ON p.company_id = c.id");
    }
}
```

The result will be

```
[{"id":1,"f_name":"fn1","l_name":"ln1","add_info":"info1","company_id":1,"company_name":"test_company1"},{"id":1,"f_name":"fn2","l_name":"ln2","add_info":"info2","company_id":1,"company_name":"test_company1"},{"id":1,"f_name":"fn3","l_name":"ln3","add_info":"info3","company_id":1,"company_name":"test_company1"},{"id":1,"f_name":"fn4","l_name":"ln4","add_info":"info4","company_id":1,"company_name":"test_company1"}]
```

**Updates based on the questions in the comments:**

`javax.sql.DataSource` is a bean that is autoConfigured by spring (unless you override the configuration or disable it). This bean is needed for the `JdbcTemplate` because it contains information about the database that on which the `JdbcTemplate` will execute the queries.
By default, it uses the following properties from the application.properties (or in the case bellow, application.yml) file. For example:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    username: someusername
    password: somepassword
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/dbname
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
```

Comment: The OP asks how to "only allow the user to select stuff and not update/drop/delete", you don't address this.

Comment: Well it's fine for now. I can always validate if the query has those words and not execute the query, i guess

Comment: That is the second question that he is asking. I consider it as an additional question. He also said that he doesnt need security in the comments, since he is going to be the only one using the app.

Comment: what's the import of that datasource?

Comment: Ok. Do I put the bean? Inside a normal java class? Do I need to call the bean or add anything to the class?

Comment: You can put the bean (the JdbcTemplate definition) in any class that is mapped by the `@Configuration` annotation. After that, you just use `@Autowired` and inject the bean everywhere where you need it.